# Pc restarts and shutdown at various indefinite times

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, reboot

One day my PC just started shutting down without an error message or anything. So I looked in the event viewer for here came the ID 41 to the vorschein. Without thinking I changed the PSU the problem remains after many attempts to fix it.

I decided to change the hardware as described above RAM, CPU, cooler and fan, motherboard as well as hard disk and Bios battery changed the problem remains the same but I now get the event ID 109 which says that the kernel has initiated a shutdown.

How can I have the same problem with completely different hardware? Has anyone ever had such a problem and can help me? It is important to know that all temperatures are okay and everything on the motherboard is properly plugged in. The moreover the computer drives up after successful shutdown again even this can be after 2 minutes directly after the shutdown or also only after a few hours.

Sometimes he makes it to Windows and sometimes he tries 10 times to boot up and shut down (before the Windows sign) until he arrives at Windows but then it can be that he only works 2 minutes to hours until he shut down again independently and restarts as he likes. Even without internet (I suspected magic packets) the error remains even after replacing my hardware remains the Problem available can someone help me?Here my Specs:

```
​
```

Cannot be the power socket tested it at a friends house problem still occurred.

CPU Temps are okay from 35C - 60C

```
CPU: Intel I-7 2600 RAM: Hyper x Ram 2x4GB 1333mhz GPU: Geforce gtx 960 PSU: 450 Watt Corsair VS Series VS450 White Non-Modular 80+
```

**Windows fixes I tried:**

- turning off fast start
- turning off hibernate mode
- turning off "automatically restart" in advanced options
- sfc /scannow to search for corrupt system files
- checking the event viewer I get EventID 109 which says that the kernen initiated a shutdown
- I completely deleted everything on my hdd and it reinstalled it - powercfg -a - powercfg /hibernate off
- disabling all devices which can wake my pc in device manager and energy options

  **Hardware Fixes:**

  - Replacing CPU
  - Replacing Ram
  - Replacing CPU fan
  - Replacing all fans
  - Replacing PSU
  - Replacing Motherboard and BIOS Battery

The Problem of unexpected shutdowns and restarts still is there.

Comment: Tried a genuine clean install of Windows? Or does the same problem persist with other OSes, like linux? Same hard drive the whole time, maybe it's freezing/failing?

Answer (score 1):

Saw your comment/answer, if the problem happens even in the BIOS before any OS has had a chance to do anything then it definitely looks like bad hardware, but it seems you've changed out almost everything already.

I do have an idea, if you're using the same case and buttons maybe the power or reset button is shorting out randomly, causing the shutdowns & restarts. I had a computer that would happen with, the reset button would sometimes short causing a black screen, looked just like a major hardware failure but just unplugging (and later replacing) the reset button fixed it.